# Azure Stream Analytics: Compact sensor data per hour?

Tags: azure-stream-analytics

How can I collect sensor events into hourly documents with an array of a subset of fields of the original message:

The incoming events have the following format:

```
{"plantId": "Plant A", "machineId" : "M001", "sensorId": "S001", "unit": "kg", "time": "2017-09-05T22:00:14.9410000Z", "value": 1234.56}

{"plantId": "Plant A", "machineId" : "M001", "sensorId": "S001", "unit": "kg", "time": "2017-09-05T22:00:19.5410000Z", "value": 1334.76}

...
```

I'd like to get the following output for each sensor each hour:

```
{"plantId": "Plant A", "machineId" : "M001", "sensorId": "S001", "unit": "kg",

  "from" : "2017-09-05T22:00:14.9410000Z", "to" : "2017-09-05T22:59:55.5410000Z",

  "datat": [

    {"time": "2017-09-05T22:01:14.9410000Z", "value": 1234.56},

    {"time": "2017-09-05T22:01:19.5410000Z", "value": 1334.76},

    ....

  ]

}
```

I create the following query:

```
SELECT  PlantId, MachineId, SensorId, Unit, 
        MIN(Time) AS From, MAX(Time) AS To, 
        Collect() AS Data
INTO CosmosDBOutput
FROM SensorsInput TIMESTAMP BY CAST(time as datetime)
GROUP BY PlantId, MachineId, SensorId, Unit, TumblingWindow(hour,1)
```

The problem is that collect returns the complete array of all origin events. But I'd like to have just the time and the value fields in it.

How can I reduce the Collect() result to this fields?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your description, I suggest you could consider using [JavaScript user-defined functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/stream-analytics/stream-analytics-javascript-user-defined-functions).

You could define a custom function to delete the useless value.

More details, you could refer to below steps:

1.Create a UDF:

[image]

2.Add below codes to the function

```
// Sample UDF which returns sum of two values.
function main(InputJSON) {
     for (i = 0; i < InputJSON.length; i++) {
       delete InputJSON[i].plantId;
       delete InputJSON[i].machineId;
       delete InputJSON[i].sensorId;
       delete InputJSON[i].unit;
    }
     return InputJSON;
}
```

3.Change the query:

Notice: replace the UDF.remove as your UDF name.(UDF.yourUDFname)

```
SELECT
    PlantId, MachineId, SensorId, Unit,UDF.remove(Collect()) AS Data,min(time) as fromdate,max(time) as todate
INTO
    [YourOutputAlias]
FROM
    [YourInputAlias] TIMESTAMP BY time
 GROUP BY PlantId, MachineId, SensorId, Unit, TumblingWindow(hour,1)
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I was already thinking about a similar UDF-based solution but hoped to find a "pure SQL" solution without UDFs.